# Why are all virtual hosts pointing to the first virtual host?

Tags: apache, virtualhost

After reinstalling a development environment on my windows 7 laptop all subdomains are pointing to the first virtual host in the .conf file!?

## hosts (c:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts)

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       admin.localhost
127.0.0.1       api.localhost
127.0.0.1       cdn.localhost
127.0.0.1       demo.localhost
127.0.0.1       secure.localhost
```

## httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName admin.localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp/www/admin
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName api.localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp/www/api
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName cdn.localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp/www/cdn
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName secure.localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp/www/secure
</VirtualHost>
```

All subdomains are pointing to the first virtual host `admin.localhost`..!? When requesting eg. `http://cdn.localhost` the dir `c:/wamp/www/admin` is showed?

I don't know what I'm doing wrong in the conf? This setup worked before reinstallation... hmmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line should be uncommented `NameVirtualHost *:80`

Restart apache after making the changes